# ip link doesn't show available device. No network interface

Tags: networking, wifi, software-installation

I recently updated to 5.12.1 and my wifi adapter stopped working. The model is TL-WN722N.
I can verify that the adapter itself works, and I have installed the driver from https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/8188eu-dkms/

`'lsusb -v` shows that the adapter is there but both `ip link` and `iwctl adapter list` do not show the adapter.
What can I do?

Comment: Do any lines in `/var/log/kern.log` mention the hardware? If so, please add them to your answer.

Comment: I dont have a kern.log file.

Comment: You might want to tell us a bit more about your system then, to try to find what the problem is.

Comment: Those logs come from kernel's messages. So run `dmesg` (or `sudo dmesg`) a short time after having booted. Search in its output for lines related to your device and add them (as well as a few surrounding lines) in the question. Anyway please also state what distribution (ArchLinux?) is used.